# Return 404 status from 404.js/.tsx page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

Created a simple 404.js page

```
import React from 'react'

import Error from 'next/error'

export default function Page404() {
  return <Error statusCode={404} />
}
```

In [[...page]].tsx:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() { ... }

export async function getStaticProps({ ... } : StaticProps) {
  ...
  if (!page) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

If I enter some dummy URL, error page is shown, but http status is 200. How can I change it to 404?

Comment: Will try to utilise https://github.com/martpie/next-with-error

Comment: next-with-error helped.

Comment: Are you using `fallback: true` inside `getStaticPaths` by any chance?

Comment: Yes. I do --> return { paths,  fallback: true, }

Comment: Does this help answer the question: [The "notFound" prop of getStaticProps has no effect on page http status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66841538/the-notfound-prop-of-getstaticprops-has-no-effect-on-page-http-status-code)?

Comment: I've solved the problem - used next-with-error HOC (_app.js) and added notFound: true,